# What are SMTP sender domain and sender email adress when using a domain in combination with mailgun and heroku

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

After setting up and verifying my subdomain (subdomain.rootdomain.com) on MailGun I want to add the correct data to send emails from my Heroku App.
My Question is: What do I have to put in for sender_email? Do I have to create an email adress on my STRATO domain in order to send emails from it or can I use some other (random) credentials? Do I have to use the default usercredentials provided by MailGun like in my example?
Also is the domain in the env vars the subdomain I registered on MailGun or is it the root domain. Can I send Emails from MailGun even though my Automated Certificate is provided to another subdomain of my rootdomain?

I have this function:

```
from os import environ
import email, smtplib, ssl
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.message import EmailMessage

def send_email(subject, text, useremail):
    host     = environ.get('MAILGUN_HOST')
    port     = environ.get('MAILGUN_PORT', 587)
    user     = environ.get('MAILGUN_USERNAME')
    password = environ.get('MAILGUN_PASSWORD')
    domain   = environ.get('MAILGUN_DOMAIN', "mydomain.com")

    sender_email =  user

    recipient_email = useremail
  
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(text, subtype="html")

    try:
            server = smtplib.SMTP(host, port)
            server.ehlo()
            server.starttls()
            server.ehlo()
            server.login(user, password)
            server.send_message(msg, from_addr=sender_email , to_addrs=recipient_email)          
            server.close()
            
    except Exception as e:
            print ("An Error occured: ", e)
    else:
            print ("Email sent!")
```

I tried various providers on Heroku. Most do not work and this is basically my second last hope. Thank you

Comment: did you ask on `MailGun`? Usually portals for mails have instructions how to configure desktop programs for mails like Outlook or Thunderbird - and you should use the same settings in your code.

Comment: sender mail should be like `user@your_domain.com` and you should have this mailbox on server because it first send mail to `user@your_domain.com` your server and later server send it to `recipient_email`